# Networkx - each node is an object how do I label and size according to the objects attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x, networkx

I have created a NetworkX graph using Python 3.6  where each node is an object with attributes:

```
{'id': 1, 'wealth': 300}
```

When I draw the graph, I want the node label to be the 'id' and the size to be based on the 'wealth', but I cannot figure out how to get the command to access these attributes.

Right now I have:

```
nx.draw_networkx(G, with_labels=False, label=[node.id for node in G])
```

However, this does not provide any labels, I have tried several variations, (i.e. `with_labels=True`) but the only label I can ever get is the object.

Comment: by the way: `with_labels=False` tells it not to show any labels.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of [`get_node_attributes`](http://networkx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/generated/networkx.classes.function.get_node_attributes.html?highlight=get_node_attributes) and [`draw_networkx`](http://networkx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx.html?highlight=draw_networkx)

```
labels = nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'id')
node_size = list(nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'wealth').values())
nx.draw_networkx(G, labels=labels, node_size=node_size)
```